# How to remove an object from an ArrayAdapter that you don't have that object's reference but have another congruent object?

Tags: java, android, firebase, reference, firebase-realtime-database

Don't get fooled by the title to think that this a spam, please read to the end.

I have a custom `ArrayAdapter` that has elements of type `News`.

I populate that adapter using my online source `Firebase`.

In Firebase there is a listener called `onChildRemoved` that detects if a database child got removed. (for those who don't know)

Here is the code:

```
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            // this way you obtain the item removed
            News news = dataSnapshot.getValue(News.class);

            // here it doesn't remove the item
            myAdapter.remove(news);
        }
```

I know that it doesn't remove the item because my `news` object doesn't reference the object in the adapter.

So here comes the question.

How do I remove an object that I don't have its reference but I have another congruent object?!

More specifically:

How to remove my `news` object from the ArrayAdapter?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to do that you should implement a `equals` methods on the news object. This method will compare the internal values of this news. FOr example, if you have an `id` field for the news, you could do something like this:

```
public class News {

    String id;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(o instanceof News){
           News other = (News) o;
           return this.id.equals(other.id);
        }else{
           return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can give myself a pat on the back cus my app is almost on the play store

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement equals() method properly in your News class. Then it will be removed even if there are two different instances.

It is about difference between

```
a == b
```

and

```
a.equals(b)
```

Of course if it is your custom `remove()` method of your `myAdapter` class you have to use `equals()` method (not `==` operator) to identify object to be removed.
All standard collection implementations use `equals()` properly.